# relation in between a categorical dependent variable and combination of independent variables

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics, analysis

I am looking for a technique which could help us find the relation in between a categorical dependent variable and combination of independent variables (*Y ~ X1*X2+X2*X3+X3*X4*), here among *X1* to *X4* we have few categorical columns and few continuous columns.

I am working on a classification problem and I want to check what combination of independent columns are highly related to dependent columns.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I correctly understand your question, but from what I understand:
You can try to convert your continuous columns to buckets, which means effectively converting them as categorical as well and then find correlation between them.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I understood what you've suggested but unfortunately I cannot implement that since I have columns like "Interest rate" where I don't want to group them since the values are very near by. However let's say even though I group few of them, are there any techniques which could say the relation between a categorical dependent variable and combination of two independent variables??

Comment: @ChaitanyaSai well it looks like it is a fundamental problem that we try to solve using all machine learning algorithms. For instance, logistic regression gives relationship between one dependent discrete variable  and one or more nominal, ordinal ,interval or ratio-level independent variables

Comment: I have tried using Logistic Regression and found very few significant combinations based on P-value, am looking for some alternatives ways which can be useful in such scenarios so that I can give those combinations to model which I get through the once I got through Logistic regression and through some other alternative ways. So, I would like to know few alternatives. Thanks